# Changing background color of done/send key on softkeyboard android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Is it possible to change the background color of soft keyboard when it popups on screen. That is having full control of the native android keyboard and customized it at will.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can not change background color of android soft keyboard while it pops up. For that you have to make you own soft keyboard.
And if you want to customize android native key board then you can do it. Take source code of LatinIME from Android repository and modify it by taking care of Open source licence. 
Also check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html